# From the matrix M, how to find the cell of vectors Vi, indicating the index line of the value 2 in each column Ci?

Tags: matlab, matrix

From the matrix M, how to find the cell of vectors Vi, indicating the index line of the value 2 in each column Ci ?

Example:

```
M=[1 0 2 0;
   0 2 2 1;
   2 1 0 2;
   2 1 2 0;
   0 2 1 1]
```

The expected output: `{[3 4],[2 5],[1 2 4],[3]}`

Comment: Did any of our answers adequately answer your question?  If so, consider accepting one of our answers.  Bonne chance!

Comment: @rayryeng: I accept the 3 answers! how to do it?

Comment: @rayryeng: then I will choose the fastest response I received !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`arrayfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) -

```
out = arrayfun(@(n) find(M(:,n)==2),1:size(M,2),'Uni',0)
```

Verify results with [`celldisp`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/celldisp.html) -

```
>> celldisp(out)
out{1} =
     3
     4
out{2} =
     2
     5
out{3} =
     1
     2
     4
out{4} =
     3
```

Comment: Nice.  I like how we used different approaches to get the same thing. +1.

Comment: This correctly handles the "column without any 2" case. +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) in concert with [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
[row,col] = find(M == 2);
out = accumarray(col, row, [size(M,2) 1], @(x) {x});
```

To double check:

```
>> celldisp(out)

out{1} =

     3
     4

out{2} =

     2
     5

out{3} =

     1
     2
     4

out{4} =

     3
```

You would use the column locations of where you found the number 2 as the binning parameter and the row locations of where the number 2 is found to group those locations together in the same bin.  The default behaviour of `accumarray` is to sum values that belong to the same bin, but instead of summing values, we group everything together into a single array and the output would thus be a cell array where each index is the desired column location and the cell contents tell you which rows contained the number 2 for the corresponding column.

This should also correctly handle the case if there are no values of 2 in a column.  The output for this particular column gives you the empty array.  For example, if we had:

```
>> M = [1 0 2 0; 0 2 2 1; 2 1 0 1; 2 1 2 0; 0 0 1 1]

M =

     1     0     2     0
     0     2     2     1
     2     1     0     1
     2     1     2     0
     0     0     1     1
```

Running the code at the beginning of the post, we get:

```
>> celldisp(out)

out{1} =

     3
     4

out{2} =

     2

out{3} =

     1
     2
     4

out{4} =

     []
```

Comment: Great use of `accumarray` with custom function!

Comment: Perhaps you should modify this so that it returns `[]` for columns that don't contain `2`. Try for example `M = [1 0 2 0; 0 2 2 1; 2 1 0 1; 2 1 2 0; 0 0 1 1];`

Comment: @LuisMendo - That's very easy.  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: @LuisMendo - Modified.  Let me know if that works for you.  It does for me.  BTW, thank you for pointing out that small flaw.  I assumed that each column would have at least one value equal to 2
.

Comment: Working now! I'd give you another upvote if I could :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yet another approach:

```
M = [1 0 2 0; 0 2 2 1; 2 1 0 2; 2 1 2 0; 0 2 1 1]; %// data
v = 2; %// sought value
X = bsxfun(@times, (1:size(M,1)).', M==v); %'
y = nonzeros(X);
z = sum(X~=0, 1);
result = mat2cell(y.', 1, z);
```

This returns `[]` for columns that don't contain the sought value.

Comment: It seems the `bsxfun` hat has switched over to you this time :)

Comment: @rayryeng My first idea was `accumarray`, but you had already picked that!

Comment: Hehe oops. sorry :(.  FWIW, I was about to use `find` and `arrayfun` but @Divakar picked that from me too!

Comment: @Divakar - I officially call this day MATLAB Monday.

Comment: @Divakar Funny indeed!! :-)